# Why is this SwiftUI state not updated when passed as a non-binding parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here's what I want to do:

1. Have a SwiftUI view which changes a local State variable
2. On a button tap, pass that variable to some other part of my application

However, for some reason, even though I update the state variable, it doesn't get updated when it's passed to the next view.

Here's some sample code which shows the problem:

```
struct NumberView: View {
    @State var number: Int = 1

    @State private var showNumber = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
//              Text("\(number)")

                Button {
                    number = 99
                    print(number)
                } label: {
                    Text("Change Number")
                }

                Button {
                    showNumber = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Show Number")
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showNumber) {
                SomeView(number: number)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    let number: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(number)")
    }
}
```

If you tap on "Change Number", it updates the local state to 99. But when I create another view and pass this as a parameter, it shows 1 instead of 99. What's going on?

Some things to note:

- If you uncomment `Text("\(number)")`, it works. But this shouldn't be necessary IMO.
- It also works if you make `SomeView` use a binding. But for my app, this won't work. My actual use case is a 'select game options' view. Then, I will create a non-SwiftUI game view and I want to pass in these options as parameters. So, I can't have bindings all the way down my gaming code just because of this bug. I want to just capture what the user enters and create a Parameters object with that data.
- It also works if you make it a `navigationDestination` instead of a `fullScreenCover`. ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ no idea on that one...

Comment: Could it be that because it is `let` declared SwiftUI decides it doesn’t need to redraw the view?

Comment: Do you mean `let number: Int` inside SomeView? I don't think this is the problem because if you uncomment `Text("\(number)")` it will work. At the point of creating this view, number should be 99. And this View is created after we update the number (verified with the debugger).

Comment: But that Text is in another view and not relevant to my comment. Anyway, it’s an interesting point about what you see in the debugger and I must say it’s not easy to understand the lifecycle of a view in SwiftUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A View is a struct, therefore its properties are immutable, so the view can not change its own properties. This is why changing the property named `number` from inside the body of the view needs this property to be annotated with a **`@State`** property wrapper. Thanks to Swift and SwiftUI, transparent read and write callbacks let the value being seen changed. So you must not pass `number` as a parameter of `SomeView()` when calling `fullScreenCover()`, but pass a reference to `number`, for the callbacks to be systematically called: **`$number`**. Since you are not passing an integer anymore to construct struct SomeView, the type of the property named `number` in this struct can not any longer be an integer, but must be a reference to an integer (namely a binding): use the `@Binding` annotation for this.

So, replace `SomeView(number: number)` by `SomeView(number: $number)` and `let number: Int` by `@Binding var number: Int` to do the job.

Here is the correct source code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NumberView: View {
    @State var number: Int = 1

    @State private var showNumber = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
//              Text("\(number)")

                Button {
                    number = 99
                    print(number)
                } label: {
                    Text("Change Number")
                }

                Button {
                    showNumber = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Show Number")
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showNumber) {
                SomeView(number: $number)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    @Binding var number: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(number)")
    }
}
```

After all that said to obtain a valid source code, their is a little trick that has not been explained up to now: if you simply replace in your source code `Text("Change Number")` by `Text("Change Number \(number)")`, without using `$` reference nor `@Binding` keywords anywhere, you will see that the problem is also automatically solved! No need to use `@binding` in `SomeView`! This is because SwiftUI makes optimizations when building a tree of views. If it knows that the displayed view changed (not only its properties), it will compute the view with updated `@State` values. Adding `number` to the button label makes SwiftUI track changes of the `number` state property and it now updates its cached value to display the Text button label, therefore this new value will be correctly used to create SomeView. All of that may be considered as strange things, but is simply due to optimizations in SwiftUI. Apple does not fully explain how it implements optimizations building a tree of views, there are some informations given during WWDC events but the source code is not open. Therefore, you need to strictly follow the design pattern based on `@State` and `@Binding` to be sure that the whole thing works like it should.

All of that said again, one could argue that Apple says that you do not have to use `@Binding` to pass a value to a child view if this child view only wants to access the value: *share the state with any child views that also need access, either directly for read-only access, or as a binding for read-write access* (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state). This is right, but Apple says in the same article that you need to *place [state] in the highest view in the view hierarchy that needs access to the value*. With Apple, needing to access a value means that you need it to display the view, not only to do other computations that have no impact on the screen. This is this interpretation that lets Apple optimize the computation of the state property when it needs to update NumberView, for instance when computing the content of the `Text("Change Number \(number)")` line. You could find it really tricky. But there is a way to understand that: take the initial code you wrote, remove the `@State` in front of `var number: Int = 1`. To compile it, you need to move this line from inside the struct to outside, for instance at the very first line of your source file, just after the import declaration. And you will see that it works! This is because you do not need this value to display NumberView. And thus, it is perfectly legal to put the value higher, to build the view named SomeView. Be careful, here you do not want to update SomeView, so there is no border effects. But it would not work if you had to update SomeView.

Here is the code for this last trick:

```
import SwiftUI

// number is declared outside the views!
var number: Int = 1

struct NumberView: View {
    // no more state variable named number!
    // No more modification: the following code is exactly yours!

    @State private var showNumber = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
//              Text("\(number)")

                Button {
                    number = 99
                    print(number)
                } label: {
                    Text("Change Number")
                }

                Button {
                    showNumber = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Show Number")
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showNumber) {
                SomeView(number: number)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    let number: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(number)")
    }
}
```

**This is why you should definitely follow the `@State` and `@Binding` design pattern, taking into account that if you declare a state in a view that does not use it to display its content, you should declare this state as a @Binding in child views even if those children do not need to make changes to this state.** The best way to use `@State` is to declare it in the highest view that needs it to display something: never forget that `@State` must be declared in the view that **owns** this variable; creating a view that owns a variable but that does not have to use it to display its content is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes, so I understand that it works with a Binding. But yeah, I was under the impression that you should only use Binding if you needed to edit the state. It seems like a leaky pattern to use Binding for every single SwiftUI variable in your app.

Comment: Additionally, what if I need to pass the variable to something which is not a SwiftUI view? In my actual app, I'm passing these values to a GameScene (not SwiftUI), and don't want to use bindings in my non-SwiftUI code...going to do a bit more research. I'm sure that Apple has recommended using non-bindings when you don't need to edit the value.

Comment: Yeah, see this tutorial from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/managing-state-and-life-cycle. If you search for MeetingFooterView, they don't use a Binding here. It's a 'little' different, but this does seem to be a recommended pattern. And I'm starting to think that it's a bug that it doesn't work in this case?

Comment: Yeah, ok...I mean, I understand your answer. And I think it's the correct answer...but it still feels like a bug to me...it seems like if you update state and then read state, it should have the latest value. And I really don't like the idea of making everything mutable in my app when it could be immutable. I think I'll have to sit with this and try to work out what the best practices for SwiftUI should be...

Comment: Apple would say « it’s not a bug, it’s a feature », but I agree there is a lack of documentation from Apple and a behaviour that can not be easily predicted. The fact that it is a bug or a feature depends on what could have been said by apple experts during the many WWDC talks: this is the place where documentation stands.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like this all stems from the fact that fullScreenCover uses an escaping closure which generally seems to be an antipattern in SwiftUI (thanks malhal for linking this article: https://rensbr.eu/blog/swiftui-escaping-closures/). I would certainly be interested in hearing from Apple engineers why they chose this to be escaping.

Answer (score 2):

Since `number` isn't read in body, SwiftUI's dependency tracking detect it. You can give it a nudge like this:

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showNumber) { [number] in
```

Now a new closure will be created with the updated `number` value whenever `number` changes. Fyi the `[number] in` syntax is called a "capture list", read about it [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/closures#Capturing-Values).

Comment: Ah yep. This is similar to what Nathan Tannar told me (see my own answer). Another way of doing this was to randomly sprinkle `let _ = number` somewhere, but I like your solution better since it's local to this code.

Comment: @plivesey Unfortunately the code in your answer will cause other problems. ViewBuilder closures supplied to Views need to be evaluated in init not in body. You can learn why here: https://rensbr.eu/blog/swiftui-escaping-closures/

Comment: I'm a bit confused...as far as I understand, the point of the code in my answer is to remove the escaping closures. Currently, Apple's implementation of fullScreenCover uses an escaping closure, but you can avoid this with the FullScreenModifier struct (or at least hide it).

Answer (score 0):

Nathan Tannar gave me this explanation via another channel which I think gets to the crux of my problem. It does seem that this is a SwiftUI weirdness caused by knowing when and how it updates views based on state. Thanks Nathan!

It’s because the number isn’t “read” in the body of the view. SwiftUI is smart in that it only triggers view updates when a dependency of the view changes. Why this causes issues with the fullScreenCover modifier is because it captures an @escaping closure for the body. Which means it’s not read until the cover is presented. Since its not read the view body will not be re-evaluated when the @State changes, you can validate this by setting a breakpoint in the view body. Because the view body is not re-evaluated, the @escaping closure is never re-captured and thus it will hold a copy of the original value.

As a side note, you’ll find that once you present the cover for the first time and then dismiss, subsequent presentations will update correctly.
Arguably this seems like a SwiftUI bug, the fullScreenCover probably shouldn’t be @escaping. You can workaround by reading the number within the body, or wrapping the modifier with something like this, since here destination is not @escaping captured so the number will be read in the views body evaluation.

```
struct FullScreenModifier<Destination: View>: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @ViewBuilder var destination: Destination
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                destination
            }
    }
}
```